# How to pass data from datepicker in view to controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a 2 datepickers in my Index view in my Home Controller. I am trying to pass the data selected from the datepickers(date in & date out) in the view to another action(reservation_step_1()) in the controller.

Code from View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
       @Html.DropDownList("location_id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    }
    </div>

    <div style="float:left">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePickerModel.dtmDateOut, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @style = "height: 30px" } })
        }
    </div>

       <div class="styled-select" style="float:left; padding-bottom: 10px">
           @Html.DropDownList("PickUpTime", new List<SelectListItem>
         {
   new SelectListItem {Text="08:00",Value="08:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="09:00",Value="09:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="10:00",Value="10:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="11:00",Value="11:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="12:00",Value="12:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="13:00",Value="13:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="14:00",Value="14:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="15:00",Value="15:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="16:00",Value="16:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="17:00",Value="17:00"}
         }, new { @style = "height: 30px" })
       </div>

       <div style="background-color: #dddddd; height: 30px; width: 30px; float:left">
        <p style="font-size: 15px; text-align:center; padding-top: 3px">TO</p>
       </div>

       <div style="float:left">
           @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
               @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePickerModel.dtmDateIn, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @style = "height: 30px" } })
           }
       </div>

       <div class="styled-select" style="float:left; padding-bottom: 10px;">
           @Html.DropDownList("DropPffTime", new List<SelectListItem>
         {
   new SelectListItem {Text="08:00",Value="08:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="09:00",Value="09:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="10:00",Value="10:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="11:00",Value="11:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="12:00",Value="12:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="13:00",Value="13:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="14:00",Value="14:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="15:00",Value="15:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="16:00",Value="16:00"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="17:00",Value="17:00"}
     }, new { @style = "height: 32px;" })
       </div>

       <div style="float:left">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
           <input type="submit" style="background-color:#DDDDDD; width: 139.5px; height: 30px;" value="SEARCH" onclick="@("window.location.href='" + @Url.Action("reservation_step_1", "Home") + "'");"/>
        }
       </div>
</div>

<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section scripts
{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function ()
        {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "+0:+1",
                minDate: "+0",
                showOn: "both",
                buttonText: "<i class='fa fa-calendar' style='height: 25px; margin-top: 6px;margin-bottom: -4px; border-style: none;'></i>"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Code in Controller:

```
using FleetHire.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Hosting;
using System.Globalization;

namespace FleetHire.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.location_id = new SelectList(db.Locations, "location_id", "location_name");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime dtIn, DateTime dtOut)
    {
        TempData["dto"] = dtOut;
        TempData["dti"] = dtIn;

        return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_1", "Home");
    }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult reservation_step_1()
        {
            string d_out = TempData["dto"].ToString();
            string d_in = TempData["dti"].ToString();

            DateTime O = DateTime.ParseExact(d_out, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            DateTime I = DateTime.ParseExact(d_in, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            var days = I.Subtract(O).Days.ToString();

            ViewBag.totdays = days;
            return View(db.Step_1.ToList());
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a NullReferenceException("Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") The lines that are causing this error are:

```
string d_out = TempData["dto"].ToString();
string d_in = TempData["dti"].ToString();
```

In the reservation_step_1 action I am trying to get the date in and date out from the Index action and get the days between date out and date in.

What is causing this issue or what am I doing wrong?

Much appreciation for any help!!

The suggestions made below have seemed to work, However I am now experiencing a problem with the DateTime Conversion

The line below throws the following error (String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.)

```
DateTime.ParseExact(d_out, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple forms (only one form and therefore only one form control will be sent). And you are generating a form control for  `DatePickerModel.dtmDateOut` (not `dtmDateOut`) etc, therefore you need to use the same model that you used in the POST method, not individual parameters that have no relationship to the view

Comment: Do not change your original question based on answers or comments (I have rolled back your changes)

Comment: Sorry Sir, I will revert them. I just need you to see what I have done

Comment: Then you append the new code your tried! (you cannot invalidate comments and answers that have already been added)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the same DateTimePicker elements on the same BeginForm. I suggest you remove this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePickerModel.dtmDateOut, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @style = "height: 30px" } })
    }
```

With just this one:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePickerModel.dtmDateOut, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", @style = "height: 30px" } })
```

Since you are already have a Html.BeginForm on the start of your code. Do this on the other DateTimePicker.

At the start of your code do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   //Put all your logics here. Its not necessary to put any BeginForm on other elements.
}
```

And as Stephen Muecke mentioned in the comment, bind your element name/id from your view to a Model that you will pass on the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(DatePickerModel objModel)
{
   TempData["dto"] = objModel.dtOut;
   TempData["dti"] = objModel.dtIn;
}
```

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested Sir, but am still getting the error. I am unsure if I have made the edits accordingly but i also edited my question to the suggestion you made so can you please tell me if I went wrong somewhere along the line?

Comment: The closing bracket of your BeginForm overlaps the script section. Close the BeginForm bracket before your section scripts.

Comment: `DatePickerModel` is not the model in the view (its a property of the model). OP needs to indicate what the model is - and its that model that needs to be used in the POST method

Comment: After making the changes mentioned, It does not seem to be giving the error any longer but I am now faced with a conversion error. I am having difficulties with the conversion from String to DateTime

Comment: What is the conversion error? What is the result after you parse it?

Comment: This line - DateTime.ParseExact(d_out, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

is kicking back this - System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What is the value of your d_out on the first place?

Comment: d_out holds the value of the date I have recieved from the view

Comment: Send here the exact value on your debug.

Comment: TempData in the HTTPPOST method is not retrieving any of the date values from the view. I manually replaced "TempData["dti"] = PMV.dtmDateIn;" with a date and it worked. But when I changed it back it returns an error all over again saying TempData holds a null value.

PMV comes from the parameter in the HTTPPOST method:

public ActionResult Index(DatePickerModel PMV)
{
TempData["dti"] = PMV.dtmDateIn.ToString("dd/mm/yy");
            TempData["dto"] = PMV.dtmDateOut.ToString("dd/mm/yy");

            return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_1", "Home");
}